# Laravel - How can I authenticate users from cached user object in Laravel? (using JWT)

Tags: php, laravel, caching, eloquent, jwt

I'm using the Laravel Tymon package for JWT user authentication.

I'm also caching every user object after a new user is created and saved in the database so that I can load the data faster on selects.

The `authenticate()` method in the Tymon package takes the token as an input and uses the user model in order authenticate the user as follows:

```
public function authenticate($token = false)
{
    $id = $this->getPayload($token)->get('sub');

    if (! $this->auth->byId($id)) {
        return false;
    }

    return $this->auth->user();
}
```

Is it possible to authenticate the token against the cached user model instead of the actual model?

I have tried one way to do this and that is overriding the `authenticate()` method in `AppServiceProvider`.

But I want to handle this on the User model instead. Which means that I want the User model to fetch the user object from cache (if it exists) instead of fetching it from the database and change/override nothing on the `authenticate` method.

Comment: caching a user model seems peculiar. can you explain why exactly are you doing that?

Comment: @SapneshNaik The database I'm using is under heavy load and the users table is called repeatedly throughout the day. Reading the data from the cache has helped me take off some load off the DB in past.

Comment: add the cache part to the question.